# Error passing union as parameter in operator<<

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out an error in my trivial code below:

```
union YunYun
{   
    int i;

    YunYun() : i(99) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const YunYun &y)
    {   
        os << y.i;
        return os; 
    }   
};  

int main()
{
    YunYun yn;

    std::cout << yn << std::endl; //This will not execute.

    return 0;
}
```

If overloaded `operator<<` is a friend or a member function of my union, the compiler will give me an error, but if it's a normal function it works perfectly fine.

Any idea, what could have cause this error?

Comment: Can you quote the exact error and give code that produces it? Because this code [compiles just fine for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe235c1b2daa5d96)

Comment: Compiles for me g++ 5.1.0  Did you forget to `#include <iostream>`  ?

Comment: Which standard are you targeting? 03, 11, 14, 17?

Comment: These are the errors I got:

1>  c:\users\rj\desktop\visual studio\vc\include\ostream(1019): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const std::error_code &)'


1>  c:\users\rj\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\practiceii\practiceii\practiceii.cpp(40): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::ostream, YunYun)'

I did not forget to include <iostream>.

Comment: Put the exact error *in* the question thanks. (Also this seems to only be part of the error because there's no error code in what you posted)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is failing for you in MS Visual C++?

Move the function definition out of the union:

```
union YunYun
{
    int i;

    YunYun() : i(99) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const YunYun& y);        
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const YunYun& y)
{
    os << y.i;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    YunYun yn;

    std::cout<< yn <<std::endl; //This will not execute.

    return 0;
}
```

Even though the definition is outside of the union, the friend declaration inside the union causes operator<< to be a friend. It appears to be a bug in Visual C++ that causes this.

Looking a little further, it seems that there are some strange rules for exposing friend functions to the outside scope.

```
union YunYun
{
    int i;    
    YunYun() : i(99) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const YunYun& y)
    {
        os << y.i;        
        return os;
    }

    friend void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }

    friend void bar(const YunYun& y)
    {
        std::cout << "bar " << y.i << std::endl;
    }
};

// without something declared outside the union scope VC++ won't find this symbol
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const YunYun& y);

int main()
{
    YunYun yn;
    std::cout << yn << std::endl; //This will not execute in VC++ w/o declaration external to union scope
    // foo(); // error: undeclared identifier (in VC++/Clang/GCC)
    bar(yn); // works in all three compilers

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From the question: *but if it's a normal function it worked perfectly fine. Any idea, what could have cause this error?* Seems to me you,re telling OP what they already know and not actually answering the question (why does this happen/what causes this)

Comment: It seems to be a compiler bug in VC++. If I replace `union` with `struct` or `class` it works perfectly.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115464/msvc-union-vs-class-struct-with-inline-friend-operators